# Listing appointments of a contact

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'd like to list the appointments that a contacts is set to as a required participating party. I'm running the following query in my organization.

The service end point is set up like so.

```
https://bazinga/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AppointmentSet?
```

And then I concatenate that with the following.

```
$select=
  ScheduledStart,
  ModifiedOn,
  appointment_activity_parties/PartyId
&$top=1000
&$filter=
  ModifiedOn gt DateTime'2014-08-21'
&$expand=appointment_activity_parties
```

This gives me a list of a few appointments and when I investigate the contents, I can clearly see a tag called *PartId* with *Id*, *Name* etc. in it. The infromation **is there**. Then I check by hand the guid of the contact I'm curious about and add another condition in the filter specifying it.

```
$select=
  ScheduledStart,
  ModifiedOn,
  appointment_activity_parties/PartyId
&$top=1000
&$filter=
  (ModifiedOn gt DateTime'2014-08-21') 
  and (appointment_activity_parties/PartyId eq guid'...')
&$expand=appointment_activity_parties
```

However, the stupid organization service says that no property *PartyId* exists. When I try adding */Id*, it says something about no support for complex data types when querying. I'm sure it's just a small syntax thingy but after a few hours and sick and tired. What do I miss?!

Comment: First you can try with https://bazinga/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/AppointmentSet/$metadata to get the full data structure of the service. And second, as far as I'm concerned, seems your query fine. Maybe there are bugs on the service side.

Comment: @QianLi It's Dynamics On-Line so that could be some limitation on Microsoft's side but in such case, one ought have heard about it somewhere... I'll try the hint of the other guy, hopefully his magic will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario behind the clause `(appointment_activity_parties/PartyId eq guid'...')` is that you want to find out appointments in the `Appointmentset` the `PartyId` of whose `appointment_activity_parties` equals a certain GUID. But you need to specify do you want to return the appointment if the `PartyId` of **any** of its `appointment_activity_parties` equals that GUID, or you want to return the appointment only when **all** of the `PartyId` of its `appointment_activity_parties` equals that GUID.

This **any** and **all** difference is specified in the [section 5.1.1.2 of OData V4 Protocol part 2: URL Conventions.](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793847)

Thus, you can rewrite your query as follows:

```
$select=
  ScheduledStart,
  ModifiedOn,
  appointment_activity_parties/PartyId
&$top=1000
&$filter=
  (ModifiedOn gt DateTime'2014-08-21') 
  and (appointment_activity_parties/any(a:a/PartyId eq guid'...'))
&$expand=appointment_activity_parties
```

And you can choose modify the `any` to `all` according to your actual needs.

Comment: +1 for awesomeness of the trick! When it comes to the version of oData - how do I ensure that the target server handles e.g. V4, as of your example? I'm afraid that I get it to work on my machine, the test machines and then, the customer will kill me because they've got some junky old crap installed and refuse to upgrade.

Comment: @KonradViltersten  For the question of OData version. You can send a simple GET request to the service and get the response headers. If there is an "OData-Version:4.0", it should be OData V4 and if there is an "DataServiceVersion:3.0;", it should be OData V3.

Comment: @KonradViltersten You can also acquire the version of the service by visiting the $metadata endpoint of the service. The value of the "Version" attribute of the "edmx:Edmx" element of V4 metadata is "4.0", while the "m:DataServiceVersion" attribute value of "edmx:DataServices" element of V1-3 metadata will be the corresponding version number. And by the way, any() and all() (or simply lambda operators) are also supported in OData V3.

Comment: @YiDing Sorry for not being clear. My bad. I meant not so much how to investigate what version of oData is installed on the target server but rather if most servers on the net tend to have the latest version of oData protocol installed. Or should one regard that as a probable (note: not potential but **probable**) issue to expect and guard against it? (At any rate it might be a moot point since, as you mentioned, both *all* and *any* are available already in V3.)

Comment: @KonradViltersten As far as I'm concerned I would say most services in the world right now are V3 services. This is partially because people wrote V1-3 services mostly using WCF Data Services but for V4 they have to migrate to ASP.NET Web API OData and it has been RTMed for only two months. But according to my observation of the StackOverflow questions, percentage of V4 questions raises every day. And there are a number of V4 stacks coming up: ODataCpp, Apache Olingo. So I think the percentage of V4 services will certainly come up.